# Tailwind text color shown in blue instead of grey

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, frontend, tailwind-css

I am working on a react js project with node and npm as a package manager.

Inside my project I am using multiple packages like heroicons and tailwind.

**Inside my footer I want the text to be grey** - therefore I am using the "text-slate-500" color inside my Footer.js file.

My **result is being shown in blue and underlined**, even though I am not using the underline property inside my code.

I am a total beginner with frontend development and also a newbie to tailwind css. So every help is very much appreciated and I am sorry in advance if some information is missing.

Here are the files:

**Footer.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { HomeIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'


export const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer className="mx-auto mt-32 w-full max-w-container px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="border-t border-slate-900/5 py-10 row-start-auto">
        <p className="mt-5 text-center text-sm leading-6 text-slate-500">© {new Date().getFullYear()} Hochschule für angewandte Wissenschaften Würzburg - Schweinfurt</p>
        <div className="mt-16 flex items-center justify-center space-x-4 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-slate-700">
          <a href="/datenschutz">Datenschutz</a>
          <div className="h-4 w-px bg-slate-500/20">
          </div>
          <a href="/impressum">Impressum</a>
          <div className="h-4 w-px bg-slate-500/20"></div>
          <a href="/barrierefreiheit">Barrierefreiheit</a>
          <div className="h-4 w-px bg-slate-500/20"></div>
          <a href="/">Deutsch - English</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  )
}

export default Footer;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "aicard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.6",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "fast-equals": "^4.0.1",
    "io": "^1.0.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */ 
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'regal-blue': '#243c5a',
        'gameblue': '#1d3f56',
        'gamebluehover' : '#122736',
        'gamebluelight' : '#244f6b',
        'gamebluelightest' :'#326d94',
        'fhwsorange' : '#dd742e',
        'gameboardconfig' : '#2e4c61',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And this is my result:
[Footer.js visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJkYM.png)

Comment: I've noticed Bootstrap in your dependencies so it may be default styling of links in Bootstrap

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I have uninstalled it, but it also doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: can you provide me a code in codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Provide classname direct to anchor link and for text-decoration use appropriate class for removing that.

```
 <a href="/" classname="text-slate-500">Deutsch - English</a>
```

Comment: I already tried it and also with other colors - but it also doesn't take any effect.

Comment: Can you provide codesandbox link?

Comment: Also a thing I wanted to mention: 

Inside our project we are working with gitlab. 
I wanted to start a new branch because I had too many conflicts - cloned an earlier version, installed everything correctly and placed my files manually.  

I did not have those problems in my older version/branch.

Comment: It also seems to me, that its not showing the same responsiveness as before and I am really wondering what the problem for this might be. 

I checked all dependencies and and all required files for using tailwind - also I don't get any error message in my console.

Comment: I think in tailwind.config.js file you need to provide that variable name and color code then it might works.